# Unable to point the difference in Kubernetes PODS configurations

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

[image: What is the difference between these 2 pod definitions? One of the left does not come in READY status ever.]

I renamed the one on the left to myredis_err and printed the logs. The logs are the same. But check the status. I am thoroughly confused.

[image]

Also, why the solution had restartPolicy as Always? The question does not mention restart behavior at all.

TIA.

Comment: I'm not clear what I'm looking at.  You mention pod configurations, but the question only has two image files and not the YAML of the pod specs.  Can you edit the question to replace the images with the text of the YAML files and of the actual error message you're getting?  Are basic tools like diff(1) enough to highlight the differences for you?

Comment: Given that redis is in memory data store which has to be always on so the restart policy of always and liveness probe has to used to keep the check always active and not only on readiness

Comment: Thanks Ali for this info

Comment: David, the diff is there on screen, which also displays Yaml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly you need to specify the liveness/readiness probe in one of the following formats:

```
readynessProbe:
  exec: 
    command: ["redis-cli", "PING"]
```

or

```
readynessProbe:
  exec: 
    command:  
    - redis-cli
    - PING
```

kubernetes will not understand the `- redis-cli PING` as you have specified it

more information can be found on the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/).

Comment: That the documenation Link for what meaningqo have mentioned https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. added the link to the answer as well

Comment: Thanks. I don't have redis cli knowledge. Looking at the question it seemed like a single command to me.

Comment: this is not redis-cli specific but how kubernetes interpretes yaml. it understands list input or exec form input ( ["do", "something"].